# What is the role of <app-root> in ionic project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I ran a blank project in ionic and got it working fine.Now i am trying to understand the working of code.What does  in this program do.I am new to ionic.Please explain to me it in details. is found in the index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Ionic App</title>

  <base href="/" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/icon/favicon.png" />

  <!-- add to homescreen for ios -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
~
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular is a single page application framework! What does it mean ? It means that the single `index.html` page will be rendered in your entire project. How it works single page applications? In an `index.html` you can find `<app-root>` tag, this tag is a selector for `app.component.ts` file if you go to the file you can see the selector, template, styles in the `@Component` decorator basically all the files that is in the decorator will be rendered and placed inside the `app-root` tag. One thing to notice is the `app.module.ts` if you not import `AppComponent` to it you project won't run because it works like this 
`index.html  --> app.module --> component` as you see module looks for component with that tag if found redirect to the component and everything that is found will be rendered in index.html

Answer (score 4):

If you really look at how angular does **[`bootstrap`](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping)**,

It's actually, the root component that Angular creates and inserts into the index.html host web page.

Every angular application will have an app-component.ts by default, if you open the code 
**`src/app/app.component.ts`**

you will see the selector named as app-root.

This one root component is usually called AppComponent and is in the root module's bootstrap array.

Comment: What is a selector

Comment: @johnson why did you remove the answer?

Comment: Thanks for answering.But i found Navruzbek answer more understandable.So when i accepted his answer .The green tick for your answer gone.